# Replace the string from a file taking input from another file using shell

Tags: linux

I have an XML file which contains below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

where, `<eName>Licensed Original`, `</eName>` , `<eName>Licensed Reversal` are static.

I want output like below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC This is New Deep</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC This is New Deep</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC This is Mayurika</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC This is Mayurika</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
while read whole_line ;
do
name=`echo "$whole_line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`
LO="<eName>Licensed Original MC ${name}</eName>"
awk -v diff="$LO" '{ if(NR==2) { print diff}
                              else {print $0} } ' southBalanceRecon.xml >>LO.xml

LR="<eName>Licensed Reversal MC ${name}</eName>"
awk -v diff="$LR" '{ if(NR==14) { print diff}
                              else {print $0} } ' LO.xml >> LR.xml
done < file.txt
```

My file.txt contains below

```
C71 This is New Deep
C72 This is Mayurika
```

When I am trying to run my code I am not getting the probable output which I mentioned above. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: yes my XML file is static

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    NAME="`echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`"
    sed "s#^<eName>Licensed Original.*</eName>#<eName>Licensed Original$NAME</eName>#;s#^<eName>Licensed Reversal.*</eName>#<eName>Licensed Reversal$NAME</eName>#" LO.xml >> LR.xml
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Wow Great. Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel with this solution:

```
sed -i -E -e "s/(Original|Reversal) .*</\1$(sed '1q;d' file.txt)</" -e 's/C[0-9]*//' file.xml

text="$(cat foo)" && echo "$text" \
| sed -E -e "s/(Original|Reversal) .*</\1$(sed '2q;d' file.txt)</" -e 's/C[0-9]*//' >> file.xml
```

---

Find the pattern `Origina|Reversal` until the `<`

```
sed -i -E -e "s/(Original|Reversal) .*</
```

---

Replace with the first line of `file.txt`

```
    /\1$(sed '1q;d' file.txt)</" -e 's/C[0-9]*//' file.xml
```

---

Copy the content of the xml file and repeat the operation, this time with the second line of `file.txt` and append the output to the xml file

```
text="$(cat foo)" && echo "$text" \
| sed -E -e "s/(Original|Reversal) .*</\1$(sed '2q;d' file.txt)</" -e 's/C[0-9]*//' >> file.xml
```